# Google Maps - Default Pins Still Showing and Obscuring Custom Icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've prepared a sample fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/F4gDW/6/

Basically I am showing the directions between two (UK) postcodes, everything works fine but after trying to move to custom map icons, the original, default `A` and `B` markers are still showing and obscuring the custom ones but I can't see how they are still being added to the map.

**HTML**

```
<div id="map_canvas" class="gmaps"></div>
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
var rendererOptions = {
    draggable: true,
    polylineOptions: {
       strokeColor: '#e02222'
    }
};

var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var markers = [];
var map;

var uk = new google.maps.LatLng(55, -3.3);

initialize();

/* In click function in production code */
var start = 'SW1A 2AA';
var end = 'SW1A 1AA';
showRoute(start, end);
/***************************************/

function initialize() {

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: uk
        // map styles excluded to save space
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

// Start/Finish icons
var icons = {
    start: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        'http://www.fprealtors.com/vendor/images/icons/marker.png',
        new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 20)),
    end: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        'http://www.fprealtors.com/vendor/images/icons/marker.png',
        new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 20))
};

function showRoute(from, to) {

    // Now calculate route
    var request = {
        origin: from,
        destination: to,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            var leg = response.routes[0].legs[0];
            makeMarker(leg.start_location, icons.start, 'A-End');
            makeMarker(leg.end_location, icons.end, 'B-End');
        } 
    });

}

function makeMarker(position, icon, title) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: title
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
}

function computeTotalDistance(result) {
    var total = 0;
    var myroute = result.routes[0];
    for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    }
    return total;
}

function toggleBounce() {

    if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
        marker.setAnimation(null);
    } else {
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }
}

function clearOverlays() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers.length = 0;
}
```

I tried adding a function to clear the markers but anywhere I've tried to use it doesn't solve the problem.

I think something is running twice but I've not found anything so far when I've been debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the option `suppressMarkers` of the DirectionsRenderer to `true`

http://jsfiddle.net/F4gDW/7/

Comment: ah, thanks, didn't know that option existed, only one thing though, you can't then click on the markers to open their info boxes, instead this error is thrown: `Uncaught ReferenceError: marker is not defined`, any ideas to have both work?

Comment: There are no info boxes bound to these markers. The error may be fixed by replacing `marker` with `this` in the `click`-callback: http://jsfiddle.net/F4gDW/8/

Comment: ah, yes, sorry, was confused by own code there for a moment, the info box was appearing on the default `A` and `B` markers, I'll just need to look up how to add that to the click handler again.

Comment: you may get the content for the infowindows via the directionsResult. For the start-marker it would be the `start_address` of the first leg, for the end-marker the `end_address` of the last leg (first  and last leg are equal in your case, because you don't use waypoints)